# How to get QuickTime player to open a non-standard video stream?

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, quicktime, mms-streaming

On some sites there are video streams, such as [this](http://switch248-02.castup.net/curet/gmp2.asp?clipmediaid=7588459&ak=null&ai=549&plid=-1&BMGroupID=58977&eref=1&ticket=%7C1%7C0%7C013B013B023B803B803BAC1E7C10F898B3BB1FE4F9A0602F84ED0F832DE0D08000F79678CF243B736706BBD6298D54D483077D5F3AA2405E18E55C5C58A7C5C95C7C783A14F4C009971D41FB875C5C81165E4ECCAC49692467EFA0ACDE436E429636AC1D7E2F4913CF89CE17D105341D) one, that I can open and view well using VLC, but on QuickTime player it doesn't load at all.

How can I view it on QuickTime Player? (particularly the main segment after the 4 second intro video)